# VSCode still shows deleted Git repository

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I recently created a local repository with `git init` and pushed the content of the folder to GitHub, it worked.
Then I thaught about it and wanted to delete this repository, because I had a better solution, so I deleted the `.git` folder.

When I execute the command `git status` in this folder, the output is: `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`. That is normal, because I deleted it.

Now my problem: When I open the folder in Visual Studio Code and select the Git window (?) in the sidebar, it still finds a repository. I have no idea why this is the case.

I tried to restart my pc and restart VSCode, but after a little loading VS still finds a repository.

Comment: go up the directory tree and find the `.git` folder

Comment: it is not the Git window, it is SCM, git is not the only SCM you can use with VSC

Comment: what do you see in the source control window? can you share a screenshot?